# How to design a general Node for a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, design-patterns

My design problem is that I'm trying to write a general class that would fit several possible subtypes. Specifically, I'm trying to write a Node class for a binary search tree, that would fit several implementations of search trees (Avl Tree, 2-3 Tree, Red-Black tree, etc.) My problem is: different Trees require different variables in the Node class in order to maintain efficiency. AvlTree need a height variable, RedBlackTree need a color variable (which an AvlTree have no use for), and so on. What's the best design solution:

1. declare many variables in the Node (color, height, balancing factor,...), and just give many constructors?
2. Have a a variable of type Object in Node, called metadata, which every implementation will use to contain its metadata?
3. Something else?

Comment: "Have a a variable of type `Object` in Node, called metadata,..." If you should go down this road, do not use `Object`, write an interface / abstract parent class for that. Why would you even want a general parent-class for the node? The node should be an implementation detail and hidden from the user. From what I understand, you only need to specify the general accessor methods (like `add(...)`, `remove(...)`, `find(...)`) for the tree, which could either be abstract or defined in an interface.

Comment: Just as you have a parent BinarySearchTree class that only contains code common to all binary search trees, create a parent Node class that only contains code common to all types of nodes (for example, a pointer to the owned data). Likewise, inherit from Node to add specialization for each type of node.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you simply use java.util.TreeSet<E>? Do you want to invent the wheel?

Comment: @Turing85 is this a good deisng? Say I'm implementing an Avl Tree. All the AvlNode class adds to the generic Node is a variable of height. Wouldn't creating a new Class just for a single variable would be considered bad design?

Comment: @RobertKock I'm learning Java, and I'm trying to learn good design. I assume this case isn't specific to trees

Comment: I am thinking a general `Node` class with the things that all trees need, and then subclasses for trees that have special requirements. For example a `RedBlackNode` with a colour, suitable for red-black trees. Each tree class knows which node type it needs, so it’s probably not so bad. You may have a `createNode` method in the tree that you may override.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah, but the differences between each type of Node are really minimal - they both use the same methods, and the difference is in just one or two variables (the RedBlackNode would need a color variable, for example). Wouldn't creating a RedBlackNode class just for that purpose would be too much?

Comment: @blz There is benefit, mainly performance-wise (speed & memory consumption). Having a base class will pin down the data structure and memory layout and eliminating some optimization techniques. For example, in the Linux kernel, the color of a RBTree node is embedded in the children pointers (in C, memory allocations are aligned to at least the arch word size so the LSB 2 bits are always 0b00 on x86)

Comment: @Yadli I didn't understand - inheritance is more or less efficient?

Comment: @blz Inheritance in this case means the definition of lchild and rchild explicitly as data fields. They will be placed at the front of the base object. I think this is also applicable to java objects: base at the front, inherited fields follow. So if one BST implementation highly rely on fast access of its internal fields, it cannot move them to the beginning of the object to take advantage of cpu caches etc.

Comment: IMHO unused fields is something that makes a program harder to read. So having the colour field only in the nodes in the red-black tree would make the program more readable and less expensive to maintain.

Comment: In a comment thread like this we can only scratch the surface. Whatever you decide, your design will be put to the test in working code, and when you get experience with it, you may well want to modify the design. Go ahead, it could be fun and you can only learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to design a general Node for a Binary Search Tree?

ok, you asked...

---

First, that is a great link below there. And will certainly expose
the breadth of your question, strictly keeping to Data Structs.

[Abstract_Hierarchies](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0ab6/283a41ab79203e740072534d44bd4f5dbefa.pdf) make everything so much easier.
At least you are thinking in the right direction. As I see some have mentioned here, at least superficially, the best approach (Language Agnostic) is always the same in OOP.

By the way, Java is an excellent language, to begin practicing OOP principles. In fact, I just deleted that paragraph...

**IFace, IFaces, FullInterface**. The secret to building any good abstract hierarchy is 'bare bones' implementation. 
(I won't implement the generics here, but Java has robust support just for this. ***java.util.collection*** this is the root of the collections hierarchy).

However, generics are virtually built into the language for you. Everything is an Object in Java. There you go...The most abstract representation of any type you can imagine.

To your specific requirements: in pseudo...or pseudo-pseudo 
that's all I was ever able to grasp. The pseudo-pseudo(whatever).

**INode** must have at least:

1. One Private DATA member *or* Key.
2. Reference to at LEAST, BUT at this point, not more than 2. 
   Child **INode**s(*a minor inconvenience here. java does not 
   give users direct access to memory via pointers, like 
   C/C++*) Obviously, this is exactly 2, but 'AT LEAST' is a 
   very important methodology when thinking about progressive 
   implementation. Just the absolute essence, no more.
3. Public accessor and mutator for private DATA.
4. Manager function Declarations.(short list, I don't recall
   whether or not operator overloading is supported in java or not)
   Can't imagine how the op equals is handled, given the case...hmmm
5. Since an **INode** is useless(not entireley) apart from its Data
   structure, This is where I would set up private access keys.
   (Java specific) this also means, in reference to the 
   Manager functions above, **INode** will not declare a 
   public CTOR. java's version of C++ friend class (ITree) 
   In your case.(look up class access key/Java). This also
   Exhibits properties of the Singleton Pattern.
   **---STOP HERE**. **This**, while appearing quite incomplete, is the 
   First stage Implementation of the abstract **INode**
   Hierarchy.

This is enough for a *Binary Tree* Data Structure.
(extend or implement) the **INode** Interface for
a concrete *Binary Tree* Node class. So far so simple.

Next, we are looking for the design provisions that will satisfy
a **BST** Node class. It is conceivable, though neither convenient nor
proper, to implement our current **INode** Interface as a
*Binary Search Tree Node class*.(no...no...no...modifications!!)it is what
it is...'Closed for Modifcation && Open for Extension;

We will Extend **INode** from our new Interface...I think I will call it **IOrderedNode** Interfaces should always have hyper descriptive
naming conventions. (*I know, what happened to mine*). Actually, it
does reflect the primary difference between a **Binary Tree**, and a
**Binary Search Tree**. A **Binary Search Tree** is simply an Ordered
**Binary Tree**. There are *implications* related to this, apparently
trivial, difference. Mainly, all of the practicality of having a
Serial Data Structure. This means, that we should go back to **INode**
and **evaluate** (NOT CHANGE!!) the private Data member.
      --------

Hopefully, we were thoughtful when considering the abstract extensibility
of that Data member. If I remember right, generics in java have been
augmented in versatility...I will leave that to you. To borrow a concept
from C++, I would have used a generic *pointer to type* of **template Arg**. Or
better yet a ***void pointer***(*can't use the asterisk there 'cause it formats my text*) doesn't get more abstract than that! **the**(*void*)(**star**), I mean;

Forget for a moment that you are using java, because all types in java are
integral types, via the hash code inherited from the Object class's
ToString() method. User Defined Types (UDTs) should be well thought out 
here, because of the disparate implementations across Data Structures that
will implement the series of IFace extensions. (pointers, *refs:* in java) are always the best initial types at the base levels. They can be
adapted to point to, or hold reference to even the most complex UDT.

Ok, back those Serial attributes we were about to exploit.
**Traversals**::***Pre-Order***, ***In-Order***, ***Post-Order***, ***Breadth-First***.  Since we are only exploring the **INode** hierarchy,
we should start considering the algorithms that will be implemented in
the associated Data Structures, and try to identify any subordinate
dependencies that will need to appear in our **IOrderedNode**

```
//I think from here on out I will just write the code...
//20 min later...this stupid @$$ message box is the worst
//dev environment I have EVER! worked in...
//......(granted it isn't that)
//40 min later in Visual Studio. Tired of working without
//a net...no KB short cts...NO TAB! no auto formatting...?

template<class T>
class IcanOnlyBeaBT;//fwd _decl 
                //or a doubley linked list, an Adapter, a...
                //keep thinking as you go...
template<class T>
class INode
{   
    friend class IcanOnlyBeaBT<T>;//this takes care of access
public:

//  At this level we have protected
//  access for derived classes--
//  EXCEPT! with TEMPLATED classes!
//  in C++ this is NOT an issue WHEN.
//  1. data members are 'captured' by
//     template instantiation
//  2. and 3. are the exact same answer
//     as 1. only I would be forced to
//     elaborate on two specific instances
//     with the only advantage being a 
//     sufficing ward on those nit-pickers
//     who love to leave comments like
//
//          "Weellll...NOT exactly"
//
//          I dont care. I would rather
//          write my explaination for not 
//          explaining further...

        /************************************/
        // (no worries here in java - C#)
        // implement now to enforce the
        // design on higher level abstractions;
        // protected access may become 
        // private in remote derived classes
        // we never want to come back here!!!
        // push dependencies up! up! up!


     INode() : whatever_Data_I_want_Ha_Ha(nullptr) {}
     virtual void SetWhatEverDataIWant(T*) = 0;
     virtual T* GetWhateverDataIWant() = 0;
     virtual T* GetWhateverDataIWant() const = 0;
 protected:
     virtual ~INode() = 0;
     T* whatever_Data_I_want_Ha_Ha;
     INode<T>*left_child;
     INode<T>*right_child;
 };

 template<class T>
 INode<T>::~INode() {} // don't worry about this it's cool
                      //...notice that   
                  // the member is protected...and pure virtual...
                  // it's just a boomerang--    

    // Notice how adaptable this Interface has become
    // after only one extension and implementation is refined. 

    // This is BOTTOM UP because we are BUILDING... 
    // ...this should be TOP DOWN as we DESIGN...
    // THINK--TOP DOWN...BUILD BOTTOM UP...

    // Push ALL negotiable DEPENDENCIES UP AS YOU BUILD.
    // Ideally, these were identified during design.
    // It rarely ever goes that way cleanly...
    // at least not for me, but try...try

    // As incremental implementation progresses, You
    // may start to identify some of these negotiable
    // dependencies...these two interfaces are still
    // super lean..and rather boring, but continue towards
    // the AVL, Red Black, Other Data structurs they will show.

    // Nodes are, for the most part, like a drawer full
    // of silverware. They CAN'T do anything unless
    // they are being used.

    // GO UP now!!!...BUT always JUST enough!!
    // No more; GOAL...to have a DESIGN SPECIFIC
    // hierarchy, that IS extensible in a MODULAR 
    // fasion, like LEGOS. ADAPTABLE to ANY COMPATIBLE
    // Data Structure, Not just TREES. Even from here...
    // there are other suitablilities coming to mind,
    // such as Graphs, Doubley Linked Lists, circular queues.
    // Nodes are common place in Data Structures...on...on...

    // Principle Attribute: ICanBe_A_BST Data Struct now.

    // fwd _decl: 
  template<class T>     
  class ICanBe_A_BST; //The BT Node was FIRST Abstraction, 
                // BST is SECOND.
                // OR a Composite Object Structure! for the  
                // Composite Design Pattern...or...or...or
                // BECAUSE, this IOrderedNode is more QUALIFIED 
                // and adaptable. LOOK HERE! Don't throw away
                // the specific sutibility of lower abstractions
                // This should be extended to fulfil design reqs
                // IOrderedNode is not intended to be a BT, 
                // IT 'IS A' BT by extension, BUT, it is a BST Node.

                // This abstract hierarchy, UPON DESIGN COMPLETION  
                // Will have pervasive extensibility @ unique levels.  
                // think {OPEN-CLOSED} open for EXTENSION, and
                // CLOSED for MODIFICATION...GOAL...DON'T...come
                // BACK inside this BLACK BOX once it is CLOSED..!  

template<class T>
class IOrderedNode : public INode<T>
{ 
              // RIGHT HERE! ALL previous implementation
              // Is abstracted AWAY. Look how clean it all is..
              // in java you would be Extending INode Interface HERE!.
              // Extending IN JAVA IS inheritance.
              // ALL public and protected members.
              // Closed for MOD. open for EXTENSION
public:                                
    IOrderedNode() : height(0) { }

protected:
//NOTICE!(I Can Be A BST Node IF!)my data is INTEGRAL & comparable.
//FOR instance a bool is unqualified--how can you order a tree
//when the only value is a 1 or a 0;
//UDT is dependent upon guess...
//THE USER who defind it(integral && comparable);

// Question: is there anything missing from this level 
// that would disqualify concrete instantiations from adequately
// filling the intended role? .....Seriously...
// I have been awake for two days now. This may need editing. 
// Regardless the process is the 
// same all the way to Red Black and beyond...

int height; //new data member; height of the tree at that node...
            //this comes in handy when computing the balance factor
            //on balanced trees...AVL, R&B,
};



/***********************NOTE:***********************
*
*   There are several considerations that have to be made 
*   when you are "leaving" data and and implementation "behind". 
*   We know we don't EVER want to come back here...
    (not a super realistic GOAL...)
*   Is the implementation specific to the level of bstraction.?...
*   YES? then leave it here. 

    IS...the DATA specific to the implementation ????
*   this deserves 4 Q-marks because, IF at all POSSIBLE PUSH
*   these IMPLEMENTATION DEPENDENCIES..UP This RESULTS in IoC
*   Inversion of Control Inversion of CONTROL INVERSION! of Control...
*   Implementation dependencies should come from higher level abs
*   to lower level Implementation...repeats you are seeing all over
    this now TLDR, are Cardinal principles of Object
*   Oriented Design. Not because I love commenting code...
    but since YOU asked...I won't leave out the 'life blood'.

*   Incidentally, there is a requisite 
    'AHAAH moment' that either comes
*       or it doesn't.
*
****************************   PERSONAL NOTE:*********************
*
*   I picked up java in the late 90's, and was like.
*   "...what the hell is an OBJECT..?" Two years of programming from a
*   procedural paradigm, in an OOP language-LATER! It hit me......
*   (I know...slow learner)...but I remember saying out loud....
*   'THAT...IS...THE...COOLEST...THING...I HAVE EVER...tripped over...
*   Consensually, OOP is considered to be in its INFANCY. 
*   Theories (opinions) are often the cause of some rather heated
*   contest. In fact, one of the most intense and persistant 
    "cival-war" I have ever encountered, nearly dominated an entire 
    forum. I didn't really know enough to have an opinion
*   one way or the other on the matter, but I remember thinking, 
    how absurd...and laughing alot.
*   The theoretical epicenter was localized on the issue of...
        wait for it...
*
*                   INHERITANCE v.s. COMPOSITION/AGGRAGATION
*
*       Hmm....Everybody knows that programming to interfaces, 
    adhereing to common sense, established design principles, 
    and proven patterns, can all be accomplished without inheriting
    from a single archtype...
*        "Not that there's anything wrong with that..." 
    I'm pretty sure, that was the vein of the row on that
         forum...Super entertaining though...
*
*******************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and decided to go with this simple solution.

```
abstract class BSTnode<K, M> {
    K key;
    M meta; 
    BSTnode<K> left;
    BSTnode<K> right;
    BSTnode<K> parent;
}
```

This simply solves the problem for your metadata.